# How to add HMR to vanilla JS files on Nuxt?

Tags: nuxt.js, webpack-hmr

I had a Vue component with a lot of JS code.
Then I extracted that code to a vanilla .js file and imported it on my original Vue component.

Unfortunately, HMR is not working with the .js file.
The Nuxt server is performing a full reload when I edit the .js file.

Comment: Using `.jsx` instead `.js` will enable HMR for that file. Not the most elegant, but seems to work.